# Simulator in ROS

Tags: simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everybody,
Can any body tell me where to find the link for Gazebo simulator or any other simulator and its related documentation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33306/simulator-in-ros/) by [srj0408](https://answers.ros.org/users/2314/srj0408/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Use Google.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=site%3Aros.org+gazebo)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[simulator_gazebo stack](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo) and [gazebo package](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo) wiki pages should have all of the documentation linked.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might also want to take a look at:

http://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-05-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you also can try [OpenRave](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=openrave).

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2012-05-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2